# Ubuntu reverse proxy blocks file view/download

Tags: 12.04, proxy

We have a ubuntu 14.04 acting as reverse proxy. Everything works fine except that on the browser when we try to view/download attached files in the application it doesn't show/download them. However just to isolate the problem if we connect directly to the server thus bypassing the proxy everything works fine, therefore it seems that it is blocking file attachments somehow to be viewed/downloaded. Thanks in advance,

Comment: So you need to check the logs of the proxy server and the client to see where it's failing. This is not a straight forward task, depending on the setup and the application. You do not include any information at all about your setup...

Comment: Please see proxy error log when reproducing the issue. [proxy_http:error] [pid 18712] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client PublicIP:51239] AH01110: error reading response, referer: http://domainname.com/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/en_USc0w84p/71013/15509eebfa0dde58acb06358d4916703/7.1.9/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.jira-fileviewer-plugin:fileviewer-pdf-worker/com.atlassian.jira.jira-fileviewer-plugin:fileviewer-pdf-worker.js